# Inconsistency between page source HTML and HTML retrieved by beautiful soup python

Tags: python, html, firefox, beautifulsoup

I am trying to attempt to scrape movie info from IMDB.  For the most part it works but for some movies the title is different in the HTML retrieved by beautiful soup then what firefox shows as the source code.  For example when searching IMDB for the witch I get this page:

http://www.imdb.com/search/title?production_status=released&release_date=2015,2017&title=The%20Witch&title_type=feature,documentary,short

So I search the movie and then I get the movie URL with this line of code:

```
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
movieLink = soup.find('a', text = movieTitle)['href']
imdbLink = 'http://www.imdb.com' + movieLink
```

Works fine for about 80% of the movies.  I started to debug and find what was causing an error for the other movies.  I looked at the 'soup' that gets returned by BeautifulSoup and noticed that where firefox shows the line

```
<a href="/title/tt4263482/?ref_=adv_li_tt">The Witch</a>
```

The soup has the line

```
<a href="/title/tt4263482/?ref_=adv_li_tt">The VVitch: A New-England Folktale</a>
```

For foreign movies it shows the american title in firefox but the foreign title in beautiful soup.  Any insight as to why this is happening and maybe a method to get the exact html shown by firefox would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the headers Firefox is sending (there are extensions for this, or you can run a proxy server on your machine and log each request) and do likewise in Python.

Answer (score 0):

> For foreign movies it shows the american title in firefox but the foreign title in beautiful soup

This is a ringer for a different Accept-Language header. Try:

```
headers = {
    ...
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
    ...
}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup= BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
...
```